# why is componentWillUnmount not firing in the React root component when application is closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, components

I need to remove cookies from the browser when the user exits the application if a certain cookie is present(using universal-cookie).

the code I have:

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    if(cookies.get("remember")==0){
      cookies.remove("userName");
      cookies.remove("password")
    }

  }
```

works on other components but I need it on the root only to fire before the user closes the app.

Why wont componentWillUnmount fire when the application exits?

Comment: define "closes the app" (logged out, close tab, close browser)

Comment: closes tab or browser or just navigates away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`componentWillUnmount` isn't supposed to be called when browser window is closed. `beforeunload` event allows to perform synchronous actions:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnmount, false);
}

onUnmount = () => {
  // clear cookies
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnmount, false);
  this.onUnmount();
}
```

`beforeunload` may not work in some browsers and isn't reliable.

This is XY problem. This has been previously handled by cookie expiration, a cookie may be short-lived but renewed periodically when browser window is open.

Currently cookies can be considered outdated in general because there are `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`. Sensitive data like credentials can be stored in `sessionStorage`. It is automatically cleared on browser exit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is exactly what I was looking for  and then some. If I store credentials in sessionStorage can I just send them as params through an api call? currently I am just making an api call with withCredentials: true.

Comment: Is removeEventListener necessary here?

Comment: @techguy2000 It's essential for any DOM event. You never want a component to live after it's unmounted and cause memory leaks. Even if it works for *root component* (as the question describes) without removeEventListener in production, there will be leaks in tests.

Comment: In this case, the browser tab is closed.  So there could be a memory leak even after the browser tab (or the app) is closed?

Comment: @techguy2000 There won't be a leak after a tab is closed. But that the component is unmounted doesn't mean that browser tab is closed, so a leak may appear. The only reason why this may be acceptable in root component is that it's never unmounted, at least in production.

Comment: You mean when window.beforeunload happens, there is a chance the tab is not or won't be closed (or refreshed)?  Oh actually, componentWillUnmount will not get called in the root component if I am reading this correctly.  That's why we need the window.beforeunload  handler, right?

Comment: @techguy2000 Quite the opposite. When componentWillUnmount is called there's a chance that beforeunload never happened... actually, you can be quite sure that it didn't. These events are unrelated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202129/discussion-between-techguy2000-and-estus-flask).

Comment: @techguy2000 Sorry, I don't use SO chats, they don't handle offline notifications. I can't say because I don't know how you use beforeunload (it seems to be misused in the OP). But root component can become a child any time during app development and things will change for it. And componentWillUnmount can still be called for a root in tests, not doing that will cause memory leaks. But if you're sure a component is a root and you don't do tests then yes, componentWillUnmount will never be called so removeEventListener is excessive.

Comment: Ok. thanks @Estus Flask for your patience in the discussions.  I guess I was kind of missing the point somewhat.  My original question should have been will componentWillUnmount ever get called in a root component.  I guess if you do it programmatically somehow it could actually be called...